# How to use Node's debug module (Windows)?

Tags: windows, node.js, debugging, module

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my sessions (using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)), and I found that it uses the [debug module](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug). However, I can't seem to enable the debug messages. It says, debugging needs to be enabled through the `DEBUG` environment variable, but I can't seem to get it to run.

The tutorial in the README has this picture:

[image]

Under Windows I get "`DEBUG` is not a command for the command-line".

So I tried setting the environment variable explicitly using:

`process.env.DEBUG = "*";`

and still nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DEBUG=* node app` will work at the command line: it'll first set an env variable, and the execute the command. Have you tried it?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy In Windows, it tells me that `DEBUG` is not a command. But now I tried it with MSYS and it works. I keep forgetting that system-dependent documentation of Node is usually tailored toward nix systems.

Comment: agree about documentation not really covering/caring about Windows. Try using the `set` command, as in `set DEBUG=* & node app`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As [Traveling Tech Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19856/traveling-tech-guy) suggested in the comment, in a Windows command prompt, the proper syntax is:

```
set DEBUG=* & npm start
```

Obviously you can replace `npm start` with whatever command you need to launch your Node.js app. Just be sure to use the `set` command and don't forget the `&` between that command and the one launching your Node.js app!

Comment: The official documentation also now includes a [note for windows](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#windows-note), suggesting to just use `set` and then run `node` afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on OSX if I include the DEBUG= line on my node start up command everything works. Id like to use the process.env.DEBUG though for ease of use, this isnt being picked up by the debug module. I've checked the var and its being set properly.

Comment: @Joel If you're trying to manually set fields on `process.env`, I'm not surprised it doesn't work. `process.env` is designed to be an interface to access your environment variables, so if you don't want to include the `DEBUG=` bit before running your Node app, just set the environment variable. macOS example: `export DEBUG=express*`

Comment: Thanks, no I'm not trying to manually set fields on process.env.

Comment: @Joel Could you explain your issue more clearly then? I'd love to help. In macOS (and other UNIXy systems) you can set environment variables in many ways, and no matter which way you do it, `process.env` should allow you to access the value. The "debug" Node module absolutely uses `process.env` to pick up the `DEBUG` variable you provide when launching your Node app.

Comment: This throwing below error:                                                                                              PS D:\code> set  DEBUG = *   & node app.js
At line:1 char:18
+ set  DEBUG = *  & node app.js
+                  ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part    
of a string.

Comment: Will ```set DEBUG=* & npm start``` work on MacOs and Linux as well?

Comment: @TomSmykowski No. On macOS and Linux, the equivalent command is `DEBUG=* npm start`

Answer (score 17):

If you are used to powershell, I recommend this setup in your **package.json**, then you can just run `npm start` so you don't type all that out every time.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "@powershell $env:DEBUG='*,-express:router*' ; node app.js"
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Install debug package with npm inside the node application

```
npm install debug
```

Open a powershell and then

```
$Env:DEBUG="name_to_call"

node path_to_js_to_execute.js
```

Inside your pgm

```
var debug = require('debug')('name_to_call');
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to install the debug module using

`"npm install debug --save"`

you will see that the following lane has been added to you package.json (which has all the npm modules charged to your proyect)

then you need to add this to import the module to the file in which you want to run the debug

`var debug = require('debug')('name_to_call');`

now we have to just put the message we want to write, for example hello

```
var debug = require('debug')('name_to_call');
debug('Hello');
```

(try pasting the code above directly to a file)

Now we just need to start the windows server with DEBUG, to do so we are going to use the `npm` package `cross-env` that will make easier to set an ENV variable across any operating system (platform agnostic)

`npm install cross-env`

Change the `package.json` and add the following under the `scripts` section

`"start-server": "cross-env DEBUG=name_to_call node server.js"`

Now to start the server just run the following in a command line (from the directory in which your project is) and you are good to go

`npm run start-server`

Comment: Again.. this does NOT work on Windows. Please consider deleting or modifying your answer, as it does not contribute anything... Sorry...

Comment: @Domi If you give me some time i'll check it out for windows :) it's been a long 2 years so maybe something changed, i'll take a look and modify it again :) I was a little junior programmer, so those 2 years will maybe make from this a better answer :)

Comment: It seems like `cross-env` works without any extra files. Just need to modify the start command to be `cross-env DEBUG=http,worker node example/app`

Comment: @user1278519 are you sure you did not install it globally and that is why is working without the `npm install cross-env`?

Comment: @AlejandroVales Oh, I misunderstood. Some answers were simply discussing how to get the `SET` to work -- which was my issue. I had thought that your files with `debug` were somehow necessary to make it work.
In short, I had to do exactly as you wrote at the end of your answer. I was confused because I was trying to access pre-existing debug information, e.g. express/knex.

`npm install cross-env

Change the package.json and add the following under the scripts section

"start-server": "cross-env DEBUG=name_to_call node server.js"`

Comment: Yeah, I did not just add that, I also added a little "begginers guide" to how to use it, just in case someone has literally no way to know why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In [Babun](http://babun.github.io) a windows shell, I run,

npm

```
npm install debug --save
```

babun

```
DEBUG=http node app
```

app.js

```
var app = express();
var debug = require('debug')('http');
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var server = http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

works like a charme for me.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Command:
set DEBUG=* & node ./app.js

PowerShell:
$env:DEBUG='*'; node app.js

Terminal/WSL (Ubuntu):
DEBUG=* node ./app.js

Answer (score 0):

There are various answers provided earlier to set the environment variable and I found that nothing is working in my Windows 11 machine. So, I tried to google how to set environment variable in windows using command prompt and I found that, using below command can set the environment variable in windows machine.

```
setx NODE_DEBUG = 'http'
```

Above command will enable debug mode for http in node which you can check in your windows environment variable setting.
you can use * instead of http if you want to enable debug mode for all node runs.
To update this NODE_DEBUG value, we need to write like this

```
setx NODE_DEBUG ''
```

But a security warning will also come in debug mode like below. So, make sure to not keep this in production site.

```
(node:28928) Warning: Setting the NODE_DEBUG environment variable to 'http' can expose sensitive data (such as passwords, tokens and authentication headers) in the resulting log.
```